# MongoDB update query returns 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value'

Tags: java, mongodb, pull

I have a collection named Entity & below is the schema to it

```
    Entity {
        Owner {
            id
        }

        Tags [
             {id : 
              name : }
             {id : 
              name : }
        ]
    }
```

I am trying to pull Entities with matching Owner id & Tag id then remove the tag from the Entities

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Tags.id", tagId).append("Owner.id", ownerId);

    BasicDBObject updQuery = new BasicDBObject("$pull", 
            new BasicDBObject("Tags", new BasicDBObject("id", tagId)));
    updQuery.update(query, updQuery, true);
```

where entities is MongoJackDaoImpl instance.

When i try to pull on an empty result matching the tag id & owner id, i get the following exception

```
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: Write failed with error code 16836 and error message 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value'
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.convertBulkWriteException(BaseWriteOperation.java:239)
```

Is there any way to check for empty result on update query so as to avoid the error ?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because UPSERT was set to false because of which update failed when there were empty records returned from the select query.

Above code is fixed by setting UPSERT boolean to true in BasicDBObject constructor

```
BasicDBObject updQuery = new BasicDBObject("$pull", 
            new BasicDBObject("Tags", new BasicDBObject("id", tagId)));
    updQuery.update(query, updQuery, true, true);
```